# Regex to match text inside HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a regex that will remove HTML tags around a placeholder text, so that this:

```
<p>
    Blah</p>
<p>
    {{{body}}}</p>
<p>
    Blah</p>
```

Becomes this:

```
<p>
    Blah</p>
{{{body}}}
<p>
    Blah</p>
```

My current regex is `/<.+>.*\{\{\{body\}\}\}<\/.+>/msU`. However, it will also remove the contents of the tag preceding the placeholder, resulting in:

```
{{{body}}}
<p>
    Blah</p>
```

I can't assume the users will always place the placeholder inside `<p>`, so I would like it to remove any pair of tags immediately around the placeholder. I would appreciate some help with correcting my regex.

[EDIT]

I think it's important to note that the input may or may not be processed by CKEditor. It adds newlines and tabs to the opening tags, thus the regex needs to go with the `/sm` (dotall + multiline) modifiers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<[^>]+>\s*\{{3}body\}{3}\s*<\/[^>]+>
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?30s4o

Here's the breakdown:

- `<[^>]+>` matches an opening HTML tag, and only that.
- `\s*` captures any whitespace (equivalent to `[ \t\r\n]*`)
- `\{{3}` matches a `{` exactly 3 times
- `body` matches the string literally
- `\}{3}` matches a `}` exactly 3 times
- `\s*` again, captures any whitespace
- `<\/[^>]+>` matches a closing HTML tag

Comment: Won't work with multiline input. My example input has newlines and this regex suffers from the same issue as mine: it also removes the preceding tag...

Comment: @mingos - I updated my answer to account for newlines. Click through to the demo.

Comment: Perfect! And a +1 for the splendid breakdown :)

Comment: `<[^>]+>` also matches `</p>` tags it needs to be `<[^>\/]+>`

Answer (score 1):

does php strip_tags doesn't work for your case?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: It works, but it's not even close to what I want. I need to leave the entire HTML in, just strip the tags around a specific placeholder text.